# Correct way to pass data in JSX clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

***First***

```
<div tabIndex="0"
  onKeyPress={this.onHandleClick.bind(null, 'first')}
  onClick={this.onHandleClick.bind(null, 'first')}>
```

***Second***

```
onHandleClick = (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).data('circle')
}
<div tabIndex="0"
  data-circle="first"
  onClick={this.onHandleClick}>
```

Is there another way to do this thats cleaner and the right way? Both of these feel like hacks: Especially using bind within the JSX.

Comment: The first one is the pure React and Javasctipt based solution which is good. Second solution will work but I feel it's unnecessary to use jQuery here

Comment: Ok great, we'll stick with the first way :)

Comment: It is ok to `bind` since:

"When creating callbacks in JavaScript, you usually need to explicitly bind a method to its instance such that the value of this is correct. With React, every method is automatically bound to its component instance." [More here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation)

Comment: Unless they're using ES6 classes, then they'd need to bind the component instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another situation that you may encounter yourself is needing the correct "this" pointer inside your callback, some arbitrary parameters and the event object itself. In that case you can do something like this:

```
<button onClick={(event) => this.handleAction('arbitrary-data', event)}> ... </button>

handleAction(data, event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // this.state.something
  console.log(`data ${data}`)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to pass parameters to your onClick handler, simply call it normally and have the function return a function:

`onClick={this.onHandleClick('first')}`

```
onHandleClick(value) {
    return function() {
        // logic that now has access to `value`
    }
}
```

Works just as well as binding, might be a little more clear. Definitely better than depending on jquery.